# ARAnchorManager.HostCloudAnchor(anchor) returns null — ARCore Extensions for AR Foundation

Tags: unity-game-engine, arcore

Calling `ARCloudAnchor cloudAnchor = manager.HostCloudAnchor(anchor)` gives null for `cloudAnchor` (where `manager` is of type `ARAnchorManager` and `anchor` is of type `ARAnchor`). I have the API key set up for ARCore Extensions with the GCP server. Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took me a while, but I fixed this.

Even though the ARCore Extensions sample gave `cloudAnchor.cloudAnchorState == CloudAnchorState.Success` immediately when calling `manager.HostCloudAnchor`, I got `cloudAnchor.cloudAnchorState == CloudAnchorState.TaskInProgress` which made `cloudAnchor == null` give `true`. I needed to loop until the state was `Success` (which took about 5 seconds each time). After the wait, the anchors are hosted without a hitch.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your feature map quality is not good. Try to call manager.EstimateFeatureMapQualityForHosting(GetPoseCamera()) to check the quality

- INSUFFICIENT: it is not good enough to resolve cloud anchor later (host anchor can be failed with this quality and you may receive NULL for cloud anchor) -> try to move device around object.
- SUFFICIENT: it is okay
- GOOD: it is good

*Note: You have to define GetPoseCamera() function. (it is easy, just includes position and rotation of camera)*

Comment: I have tried this when the FeatureMapQuality is GOOD, and it still gives null.

Comment: Did you check cloudAnchor.cloudAnchorState to get the error

Comment: I did that today and fixed the issue. I will write a solution with my findings.